# Binary operator expected error when running a bash script against a directory other than the one the script is currently located in

Tags: linux, bash

I am very new to bash scripting first and foremost.  I wrote a script that checks for entries inside of a directory and prints information about the entries.  If the entries are files it prints the file size and if there are directories it prints how many items are in those directories.  When I run the script against the directory it is located in the script completes successfully.  If I run the script against another directory I receive the error "Binary operator expected".  Is this to be expected?  Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Print the contents of a directory with details on files and directories

files=( $1* )
count=0
for entry in $1/*
do
    if [ -d $entry ]
    then
        for f in $entry/*
            do
                let count=count+1
            done
        echo $entry ":" "This is a directory with $count files present."
        let count=0
    else [ -f $entry ]
        echo $entry "This is a file of" $(wc -c <"$entry") "bytes."
    fi
done
```

I'm sure this code isn't perfect and most likely has an easier method so I am just looking for some advice.  Thank you for any help.

FurmanTheGerman

Comment: How do you run against another directory? What is your current directory at the time?

Comment: Hey @FurmanTheGerman First, always quote your variables (e.g. `"$entry"` and `"$1"`) Second, proceed step by step and use `#!/bin/bash -v` or `#!/bin/bash -x` to see what's going on.

Comment: I think I may have made it work and I also realized the code I placed had $(ls) which was supposed to say $1/*.  Thanks for the comments gildux I will do that.

Comment: The command line I am running looks like ./script.sh ~/Downloads @PM 77-1.

Comment: Your updated version of the script can produce this error, but your previous one could not. Please be sure not to make any modifications to the script after asking about it on SO, because then the code you posted goes out of sync with code you're running, and the error messages stop making sense. Also see [Why should I post complete errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) for the incredible amount of information you're leaving out by only posting the "Binary operator expected" part of your error

Comment: @gildux if I edit and add "" to all variables would it look like this?  echo "$entry" ":" "This is a directory with "$count" files present."

Comment: `he error "Binary operator expected"` - isn't there like `bash: something:line_number: something: something: Binary operator expected`? Please post a full error message

Comment: @that other guy Thank you for pointing out my mistake.  When you say the previous version couldn't produce this error but the current one can what does that mean?

Comment: It means that you will see "Binary operator expected" if you run the current version script on a directory that contains a file with spaces (due to missing quoting). The previous version would *not* have shown this error, and would instead just have counted incorrectly.

Comment: So the error was with the $entry/* on line 7 not having quotations around the variable?  I believe the binary operator expected error occurred on line 7 specifically and I did forget to mention that in my original posting which was my mistake.

Comment: Nooo :D I meant `if [ -d "$entry" ]` and `[if -f "$entry" ]` (to ensure blanks/spacing in the entry are preserved instead of being seen like different words), but `echo "$entry : This is a directory with $count files present."` and `echo "$entry This is a file of $(wc -c <"$entry") bytes."` (but of course, `echo` can have many arguments so not make much difference except that it's more readable)

Comment: [Filenames and Pathnames in Shell: How to do it Correctly](https://dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html#wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

for entry in "$1/"*; do
  if [ -d "$entry" ]; then
    count="$(printf '%s\0' "$entry/"* | grep -cF '')"
    printf '%s : This is a directory with %d files present.\n' "$entry" "$count"
  else
    if [ -f "$entry" ]; then
      size="$(wc -c <"$entry")"
      printf '%s This is a file of %d bytes.\n' "$entry" "$size"
    fi
  fi
done
```

- Removed unused assignment with missing quotes around the `$1` argument:
  `files=( $1* )`
- Fixed missing quotes around the `$entry` variable:
  `if [ -d $entry ]`
- Replaced loop with single assignment, broken indentation and missing quotes around the non-globbing part of the path `$entry/`:

  ```
      for f in $entry/*
          do
              let count=count+1
          done
  ```
- Replaced `echo` mixing literal and variables with missing quotes by a proper `printf`: 
  `echo $entry ":" "This is a directory with $count files present."`
  `echo $entry "This is a file of" $(wc -c <"$entry") "bytes."`
- Added missing quotes around the `$entry` variable and added missing `if` block:
  `else [ -f $entry ]`

Explanations about counting the entries in the directory without running a shell loop:

`printf '%1s\0' "$entry/"* | grep -cF ''`:

- `printf '%1s\0' "$entry/"*`: Prints a null delimited list of all files.
- `| grep -cF ''`: Pipe it into `grep` to count the `null` characters (1 per entry)